# Html Css Footer on mobile website

Tags: css, html, mobile, footer

The website that i am coding adjusts based on the size of the screen. The only issue is the footer that i coded at the moment is very messy, and when i view the website on a smaller device, the footer goes to the middle of the screen instead of being at the bottom.

here is the code, any help would be appreciated:

[image: Footer at bottom]

CSS

```
#fcontain{
  width:100%;
  background:white;
  opacity:0.9;
  left:-0%;
  margin-top:6%;
  padding-left:30%;
  position: absolute;
}
 #footer .column {
 width: 100%;
 opacity: 1;
}
 #footer .column div{
 margin: 1%;
 height: 100%;
 background: white;
 opacity: 0.8;
 width: 20%;
 float: left;
 position:static;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="fcontain">
<div id="footer">
    <div class="column">
        <div><img style="width:{{ settings.home_image_f }}px" src="{{ 'home_image_w.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="{{ shop.name | escape }}" /></div>
        <div><img style="width:{{ settings.home_image_f }}px" src="{{ 'home_image_w.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="{{ shop.name | escape }}" /></div>
        <div><img style="width:{{ settings.home_image_f }}px" src="{{ 'home_image_w.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="{{ shop.name | escape }}" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: google sticky footer.  also if you are wanting to center the footer divs, make them `display:inline-block` and add `text-align:center` on the column.  Saves you from adding specific left padding to #fcontain

Comment: i deleted the left padding from #fcontain and added what you said onto the css file, but the images stayed on the left, is this because it is on float:left?

Comment: Ah yes - remove the float:left if they are display:inline-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `pisition:absolute`on the container. The footer should rest in the end of your HTML file and it will suffice.

General remarks:

1. I believe you should delete the  fcontain. the footer  is
   enough.
2. Use `<footer>` instead of `<div id="footer">`

Comment: yeah i need to clean up the way the footer is coded, pretty messy right? aha

Answer (score 0):

If you want footer to always at the bottom of the screen you should use `position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute;`.

```
#fcontain {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b4vsLsjb/

Comment: works, but the only problem is there's no scroll bar now, just wanted the top few pixels of the footer showing, and the user can scroll down to view the rest

Answer (score 0):

You want the footer to be always at the bottom, right? Try `bottom:  0%` or `bottom:  0px`.

Let me know if it worked!